# Android audio streaming error

Tags: android, stream, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to create a player. I'm using Android MediaPlayer class.

Here are the stream links I'm trying to use:

http://streaming15.hstbr.net:8124/live - This one is working, mpeg format.

http://streaming15.hstbr.net:8198/live - This one is not working. AAC format.

http://radios10.ciclanohost.com.br:15300 - Is not working too, mpeg format (not 100% sure).

Here is my code:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

try {                                    
    player.setDataSource("http://radios10.ciclanohost.com.br:15300");
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    wifiLock.acquire();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.start();
        progress.setAlpha(0);
    }
});

player.prepareAsync();
```

In the second and third links, I'm getting "**MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)**", what means "**Unknown Error**"

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: 
- It works in virtual device

Comment: Which Android version are you targeting? Seems that this stream is AAC+ which was not supported before 4.1.

Comment: Using sdk 19 as min version. Testing on Lollipop